# Django: order_by multiple fields

Tags: django, django-orm

I am getting `order_by` fields in the form of a list.
I want to order by multiple fields with Django ORM.
List is like below:

```
orderbyList = ['check-in','check-out','location']
```

I am writing a query like this:

```
modelclassinstance.objects.all().order_by(*orderbyList)
```

Everything I'm expecting in a list is dynamic. I don't have predefined set of data. Could some tell me how to write a Django ORM with this?

Answer (score 157):

Try something like this

```
modelclassinstance.objects.order_by('check-in', 'check-out', 'location')
```

You don't need `.all()`  for this

You can also define ordering in your model class

something like

```
class Meta:
       ordering = ['check-in', 'check-out', 'location']
```

Comment: Thanks i got it..i got from other link.
modelclassinstance.objects.order_by(*orderbyList)

Answer (score 12):

**Pass orders list in query parameters**
eg : yourdomain/?order=location&order=check-out

```py
default_order = ['check-in']  #default order
order = request.GET.getlist('order', default_order)
modelclassinstance.objects.all().order_by(*orderbyList)
```

Answer (score 1):

`modelclassinstance.objects.filter(anyfield='value').order_by('check-in', 'check-out', 'location')`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a list of stringified arguments of the database table columns (as specified by your ORM in the respective models.py file) to the `.order_by()` method on the return query set like so. `shifts = Shift.objects.order_by('start_time', 'employee_first_name')`. By notation,`.order_by(**args)`, will help you remember that takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```python
listOfInstance = modelclassinstance.objects.all()

for askedOrder in orderbyList:
    listOfInstance = listOfInstance.order_by(askedOrder)
```

Comment: modelclassinstance.objects.order_by(*orderbyList) is better way to order_by

Comment: According to Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) this way doesn't achieve the desired result -- "Each order_by() call will clear any previous ordering."

Comment: This is ultimately useless as the List of instance is never saved

Answer (score -7):

What you have to do is chain the querySets, in other words:

```
classExample.objects.all().order_by(field1).order_by(field2)...
```

Comment: Don't do that. each `order_by()` call will clear any previous ordering. For example, this query will be ordered by `field2` and not `field1` !!!