# Django order_by on two fields, but one needs to be reversed

Tags: django, django-orm

I figured out how to do an order by with multiple fields thanks to this post:

[Django: Order_by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564694/django-order-by-multiple-fields)

But I ran into the issue of, one field is a number, the other is a persons name.  I need it to be ordered in descending from the highest dues to the lowest, but within that be sorted by name in alphabetical order.

I tried this:

```
  invoice_items = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice__exact=inv.id).order_by('dues', 'provider').reverse()
```

It does the dues right, goes from group of highest dues like 350 to lowest, but then the names are also reverse so top of the list are names starting with Z y etc...

What I need:

```
Bob  350
Carl 350
Mike 350
Thomas 350
April 200
Gary 200
etc..
```

instead what I get:

```
Thomas 350
Mike 350
Carl 350
Bob 350
Gary 200
April 200
```

Not sure the right syntax to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
invoice_items = (InvoiceItem.objects
    .filter(invoice__exact=inv.id)
    .order_by('-dues', 'provider'))
```